# Google App Engine Blobstore - print HTML code in the file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm using the Google App Engine Blobstore service to store HTML files. These files correspond to webpages I'm trying to allow my users to edit and update.

If I have HTML files in the blobstore, what would be the easiest way to fetch the HTML code from the files stored and display the code in a TextArea etc.? Then how would I go about updating that file in the blobstore?

I know there is the fetchData method which returns a byte array, so how could I display the plain text HTML code from an HTML file in the blobstore?

Comment: figured it out. I grabbed the byte array using the blobKey passed through a GET paramater, and then used fetchData(blobKey, 0, BlobstoreService.MAX_BLOB_SIZE-1);

To print the byte array as readable HTML code:
<textarea id="content" name="content" rows="15" cols="85">
       <% for(int i=0; i<blobData.length; i++){%><%=(char)blobData[i]%><%}%>
       </textarea></td>

Answer (score 1):

I'am also storing HTML and TXT files, but I store these files in a blobproperty of the datastore.

```
args['text_area'] = db.Blob(db_block.content).decode('utf-8')
```

I use codemirror to edit the files / the texterea. Works excellent.
Updating :

```
db_block.content = db.Blob(args['text_area'].encode('utf-8'))
db_block.put()
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. I grabbed the byte array using the blobKey passed through a GET paramater, and then used:

`fetchData(blobKey, 0, BlobstoreService.MAX_BLOB_SIZE-1);`

To print the byte array as readable HTML code:

```
<textarea id="content" name="content" rows="15" cols="85"> 
<%for(int i=0; i<blobData.length; i++){%>
<%=(char)blobData[i]%><%}%> 
</textarea></td>
```